# Extract a sentence in which the matched word is present

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to pick the whole sentence(We quote as follows:   After the biggest gold slump in three decades left investors heartbroken, they\u2019re following Taylor Swift\u2019s advice and never, ever getting back together) using mentioned code below.   I am able to extract the string after gold occurance but not the characters before it.

This is an example I just want to create a code to pick the sentence from text wherever its coming in the start of the text or at the end of the text or in the middle of the text

I think If I will be able to pick the text between (.) to (.) if possible

```
var str = "This rally in gold will fail!  The consensus on this    market view is as great as we saw at the beginning of the year on strong economic growth and rising interest rates!  Bloomberg captured the sentiment well in a June 24th article.  We quote as follows:   After the biggest gold slump in three decades left investors heartbroken, they\u2019re following Taylor Swift\u2019s advice and never, ever getting back together.; 
var n = str.indexOf("Swift");
var res = str.substr(n, str.indexOf(".")-n);
```

Comment: You want two find the text between two full stops?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I removed unused code from the question. This is probably a typo, but note that `str` isn't closed: `var str = "this together.;` - no `"`. I didn't fix it.

Comment: Give us the input text, and what you'd like the function to return, based on the input text.

Comment: Yes Tushar and nu11p01n73R. I want to exttract the text between two full stops

Answer (score 1):

Usually I'd do this with a regex as follows:

```
(?<=.\s+|^)[^.]*Swift[^.]*\.
```

Which basically means »Take characters that aren't a full stop (`[^.]`), as many as you want (the `*` after that); somewhere in there has to be ›Swift‹. Also there has to be the beginning of the text or another sentence end before that (`(?<=.\s+|^)`). And it has to end with a full stop (`\.`).«

However, this doesn't work in JavaScript because there is no lookbehind, least of which arbitrary-length (to account for spaces after the full stop). The best you could do would be to match the end of the previous sentence as well and strip it off afterwards, or just use a capturing group for the part you're interested in:

```
(?:.\s+|^)([^.]*Swift[^.]*\.)
```

It's all about patterns, really. You want a sentence that contains »Swift«. Such a sentence consists of a part before the word to look for (potentially empty), and a part after the word to look for (potentially empty). It also ends with `.`. If you approach the problem from that angle, it's actually fairly simple to convert into a regex, as seen above.

In fact, we can even do better, since we know how regexes work with matches:

```
[^.]*Swift[^.]*\.
```

should suffice as well. The part `[^.]*` won't ever match a `.`, so it cannot start within a previous sentence. Thus the *first* possible position where the match can start is at the start of the sentence that contains the word to search. Incidentally, this regex should work in JavaScript just as well.

To complicate matters, sentences are also not just ended with a full stop, but sometimes also with exclamation or question marks, as [Soana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3436255/soana) rightfully notes (I thought about that while reading the question, but not while writing the regex – short-term memory is fun). So the regex should rather look something like this:

```
[^.!?]*Swift[^.!?]*\.
```

Comment: Aren't "?" and "!" also sentence-endings?

Comment: You're totally right. Sorry. I actually managed to forget them in between starting to answer and hacking on the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var str = "This rally in gold will fail!  The consensus on this    market      view            is as great as we saw at the beginning of the year on strong economic growth and rising interest rates!  Bloomberg captured the sentiment well in a June 24th article.  We quote as follows:   After the biggest gold slump in three decades left investors heartbroken, they\u2019re following Taylor Swift\u2019s advice and never, ever getting back together."; 

 var a=str.split('.');
 for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
 if(a[i].indexOf("Swift")>-1)
    console.log(a[i]);
}
```